# define personal before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want define a `before_filter` like `authentication_user!` in devise. In this project, I have a `user` model that generated with `devise` and `role` that set off the role of user. Now I want create a `before_filter` that I check user permission for reach out controller. Below code show models:

`user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_one :role
  before_create :build_role
end
```

`role.rb`:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

`Role` have 2 boolean column: superadmin, admin. I want just superadmin have permission to reach out some controller. For this, I define below function in `application_controller.rb`:

```
private
  def authorize_superadmin!
    unless current_user.role.superadmin?
      render :status => 411, :json => { :success => false, :info => "Not SuperAdmin" }
    end
  end
```

But when I use `before_action :authorize_superadmin!` in controllers, I get below error in server log:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms (Views: 0.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I think I don't define correctly the before_action. How can I solve this problem? Or whats the correct way to define it?

Comment: what error do you have?

Comment: @mgh give us the error, not the HTTP return code.

Comment: @Geoffroy I post server log and I cannot find the error. I'm not sure about definition. I search, but not found any useful documentation about create personal `before_action`.

Comment: @mgh your syntax is correct, but you still didn't gave us the actual error, which will be more useful! Run in development, not prod if needed.

Comment: You probably have a standard error in your code... Like "unknow method  superadmin? for nil:NilClass", or something else.

Comment: @ForgetTheNorm I check server log, and I found just `500 Internal Error`.

Comment: @mgh You have to run your server with full log. Like in development. Full log show you the line of the current error, not just "500".

Comment: @ForgetTheNorm I use `rails server -e development`, but not see any change in rails server.

Comment: @mgh and did you access your website on localhost:3000 then ? It's not possible you don't see something more !